# Cassandra null pointer and no information in logs

Tags: cassandra

I've installed cassandra 2.0. But then I am starting it using `sudo service cassandra start` it crashes. Only thing which appears in the `cassandra.log` is `Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.lang.NullPointerException`.

How does it possible to understand what is going on there? All what I remember that I've changed some path `JAVA_HOME` in alternatives not sure if it causes a problem.

I am on:
Centos 6
java -version 1.7
Cassandra 2.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7254
It happens when you try to start another instance