# Unable to start cqlsh in Mac OS X?

Tags: cql, cql3, cassandra-2.0, cqlsh

I have installed `cassandra 2.0` successfully. When I try to start `cql 3` I get no such option:

```
cassandra -v
2.0.9
./cqlsh -3
Usage: cqlsh [options] [host [port]]

cqlsh: error: no such option: -3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once Cassandra is started (I guess in localhost with default settings) you can connect using

```
./cqlsh localhost
```

if you want start it with a specific (older) version you can do

```
./cqlsh --cqlversion=X.Y.Z localhost;
```

where X.Y.Z is the version (eg: 3.1.0)

Comment: I tried this: my prompt never comes back:  ./cqlsh --cqlversion=3.1.0 localhost

Comment: Try starting without version, what happens? IS cassandra started? Did you start it with sudo?

Comment: I was running cassandra before, Now I restarted and I get Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: If you don't have important informations inside your db try to delete commit log (usually located under /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog) -- what else the log is saying?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24120676/cassandra-null-pointer-and-no-information-in-logs - give a look here

Comment: Thanks that helped: Now I can run. but why is it showing thrift protocol. I thought cql3 does not use thrift :  Connected to tutorial at localhost:9160.
[cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.9 | CQL spec 3.1.0 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]

Comment: and if you could help with this. it will be great http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24964211/unable-to-run-cassandra-cluster-manager-in-mac-os-x-unavailablesocketerror

Comment: Please close this thread so people will know you solved your problem.